# Can not use Django-rest-auth in Django4.0 ; ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

For now I am building the Django Rest Framework in Django4.0 and Django-rest-auth.
I knew the django4.0 does not support the ugettext_lazy. it support the gettext_lazy instead of.
I installed the django-rest-auth==0.9.5 in my app. and then it raised the issue.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation'
```

Here is my settings:

```
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [        
    'escapejson',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'rest_framework',    
    'rest_auth',    
    'drf_yasg',
    'django_jsonfield_backport',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]
INSTALLED_APPS = LOCAL_APPS + DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS
```

In Django4.0, Can not I use the django-rest-auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `dj-rest-auth` instead of `django-rest-auth`, `dj-rest-auth` is a newer fork of `django-rest-auth`.

so there setup and configuration and migration with `allauth` are all the same.

and worry not `dj-rest-auth` uses `gettext_lazy`.